# Simple arithmetic average in Python

Tags: python, loops, math, average

I'm a total newbie on Python and I would like to calculate the arithmetic average.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

average=sum(a)/len(a)

print('The average is:' ,average)
```

I'm aware that such code do solve my problems but that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I want the user to be able to type the number of terms of the arithmetic average and I would like him to be able of typing them separatley on different lines. So I thought the right thing to use was For Loop. I came out with something like this:

```
n = input('Number of terms')

for i in range (1,int(n)+1):

    a=input('Term number '+str(int(i))+': ')
```

I know that all I need to do know is to find a way to sum all values of a typed on each loop and divide this number by `int(n)` but I have no idea how to do that.

Can you guys help me with that?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you are using Python 3, `input` returns a string. Not an integer (or floating point) number. If you're using Python 2 instead, you shouldn't be using `input` but `raw_input`.

Comment: Since you want to save a _sequence_ of values, it's natural to use some kind of _sequence_ type, what about [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)?

Comment: Evert, I'm using Python 3.
And Rogalski, I'm not sure how to use lists properly so I tried to solve this with only the very basic knowledge I have. hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = input('Number of terms')
acc = 0
for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
    a=input('Term number '+str(int(i))+': ')
    acc += float(a)
print('The average is ',acc/int(n))
```

The idea is to create an accumulator variable `acc` to which the entered numbers are added. After the loop `acc` is equal to the sum of all numbers entered. Divide it by the number of terms and you get the arithmetic average.

Comment: Isn't it word for word the same as my answer?

Comment: Oh, I see! I had a problem using this accumulator variable. I'll read more about this. I think the problem has ben solved haha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
n = int(input('Number of terms'))
sum = 0
for i in range (1,n+1):
    a=int(input('Term number '+str(i)+': '))
    sum += a
avg = sum/n
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got this error message:

"line 8, in <module>
    a*=a
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"

Comment: `a` is an `int`. We explicitly cast it as `int` in `a=int(input('Term number '+str(i)+': '))`. Are you sure you cast it?

Comment: Yes I did. I just ctrl+c ctrl+v what your answer. I'm using Python 3 btw.

Comment: `a` should be a float to allow the user to enter non-integral numbers.

Comment: @SvbZ3r0, what I posted is my entire code! I know it is incomplete but I just didn't know how to proceed. hehe

Comment: @LucianoInfanti Your error occurs in line 8 and is caused by `a*=a`. That part isn't here. So i thought there'd be more to it

Comment: @SvbZ3r0, that's something I added after posted my question here 'cause I was still trying to solve that! Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help! =)